# Call JavaScript function(with parameters) by onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I cant use PHP variables to use as parameters for my function.

The function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(id,name) {
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
}
</script>
```

And this is PHP part:

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction($intvar,$strvar)' type='button'>ClickMe</button>";
```

the call works when I use numbers like this: myFunction(0,1)
but I need to use variables to call myFunction.

Please Help, thanks.

Comment: change alert(ide); to alert(id);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try this
`function myFunction(ide,name) {` change insted of id => ide
    `echo "<button onclick='myFunction(".'"'.$intvar.'","'.$strvar.'"'.")' type='button'>ClickMe</button>";`

Answer (score 5):

Good practice is to echo json encoded version of variables, this way you ensure that strings are properly quoted:

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction(" . json_encode($intvar) . "," . json_encode($strvar, JSON_HEX_APOS) . ")' type='button'>ClickMe</button>";
```

Comment: It will if you provide a flag JSON_HEX_APOS.

Comment: I try with json_encode and works too, thanks too much.

Comment: But now if double quotes are used for the attribute.. *sigh*. The problem is there is not (nor has there been) a *good* way to supply values as JavaScript arguments in attributes. So much for being a[n HTML] 'template' language ..